# install4j update using current configurations

Tags: updates, install4j

I am new to developing and I am confused. I used install4j to build an application and I have to add an extra update option on the welcome screen that updates using current configuration and does the update without GUI.. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that, but it requires a thorough understanding how updates work in install4j. There's no quick step-by-step list that you could follow here.

The general strategy would be this:

On the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step, add a new application using the template "Updater with silent version check". Study the screens an actions and figure out how they work together in order to download and execute an update installer.

Then move pieces of that logic into the installer as required.

Comment: Thank you! But I would like to create a "standalone" update otpion that the user can start manually. There is not yet a central server where he can downloadds updates. The updater should only overwrites the jar files and "jump" from the welcome screen to the last screen.. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible to download single files by using "Download file" actions. You can also, download a ZIP file and extract it with an"Install contents of ZIP file" action.

Comment: But I do not want to download anything.. I just want an updte option that overwrites the files created by the installation and skip the dialogs between the welcome screen and the last screen, .

Comment: Then you don't have an updater problem, you just run the installer. Screens can be freely configured. There is no fixed sequence of screens or actions.